# Percentage Calculation for values less than 1 and greater than 0

Tags: java

I am trying to display the percentage using BigDecimal.

for example if i have to do

```
    double val = (9522 / total ) * 100;

    System.out.println("Val is :" + val);
```

where total is 1200000.

I want to display the calculation as a percentage but since the calculation comes to a value less than 0 , I am unable to display the percentage

I also tried

```
    BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal((9522 * 100 ) / total);
    BigDecimal roundValue = decimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("decimal: " + decimal);
    System.out.println("roundValue: " + roundValue);
```

but with the same result.

How can I display the percentage even if it is in Decimals?

Comment: It's a crowded question :-D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you are doing integer division.

If you want fractional results, you need to do floating point division.

```
double val = (9522 / (double) total) * 100;
```

Casting one of your operands to a double will cause Java to perform the correct type of division instead of defaulting to integer division.

Answer (score 3):

You have to inform Java that you want at least one of the numerator or denominator treated as a double, to make sure the result is a double.

This will work:

```
double val = ((double)9522 / total ) * 100;

System.out.println("Val is :" + val);
```

Answer (score 3):

> BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal((9522 * 100 ) / total);

This is *not* how you do operations on `BigDecimal`: by the time the `BigDecimal` is constructed, the precision is gone, because the calculation `(9522 * 100 ) / total` is done at compile time. That's why the result is the same as with integers: in fact, the entire calculation is done in integers.

Here is how you calculate with `BigDecimal` objects:

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(9522)
    .multiply(new BigDecimal(100))
    .divide(new BigDecimal(total));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you divide two integer you will get the result truncated. Add a `.0` so that it is converted to floating point, and then you will not get a truncated result

```
new BigDecimal((9522.0 / total) *100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing a cast.

```
double val = (9522 / (double)total ) * 100;

System.out.println("Val is :" + val);
```

My suspect is that total is an int, and hence 9522/1200000 results in an integer, which is truncated to 0 because the operation implies that the result must be smaller than 1. If you convert total to double the result is going to be a double, and you will be able to retain the decimals.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's a request for the poster to clarify ("Can you try this and tell me what happens?"), and should be posted as a comment to the question instead of an answer. Answers should do exactly that - provide an answer to the question. If you need more details or information, comments are the way to ask for them.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I felt like this was faster because yes, I had a doubt about the original problem, but there was a good chance that I got it right (we all did). I'll erase the first line and correct a few terms.